# Get "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions" if I set the ignoreUndefinedProperties setting on firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set the ignoreUndefinedProperties flag on firestore because I often save some deeply nested objects that have a lot of optional fields that could be undefined. With that flag set though I get this error from Firebase whenever I make a call to firestore:

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new Nr (http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:45522)
    at http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:169449
    at cf.onMessage (http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:170279)
    at http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:168331
    at http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:168736
    at http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:113756
```

If I comment out just the code that sets that flag then everything works fine. I thought the issue might be that I am trying to access firestore before setting the flag, so I tried putting this code in my main.ts file before I bootstrap my app:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

declare var firebase: any;

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

// init firebase before anything else calls it
firebase.firestore().settings({
  ignoreUndefinedProperties: true
});

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

For some background I am making an Angular web app that will be hosted on Firebase Hosting so I don't have access to modify the init script for setting up all the firebase libraries, and as per the instructions here I let the hosting init.js script handle initializing all my firebase applications: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

So in my index.html I have:

```
 <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
      <script src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

      <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
      <script src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
      <script src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
      <script src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
      <script src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>

      <!-- Initialize Firebase (since using firebase hosting no need for config object) -->
      <script src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>
```

Any ideas on how I can set this flag to true?

Comment: Have you tried to change permissions for read, write: if it’s set to false change it to true. You can do this inside: database —-> rules ? NOTE: Bad thing about this is that you’re security is actually being DISABLED

Comment: Could you please point where are you initializing firebase variable? And how are you doing it?

Comment: As mentioned in the question I am using Firebase hosting, so the provided init.js script is doing the initialization.

Comment: Please have a look into the [Firebase Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) and re-check if you are initializing the [Firebase Config object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object).

Comment: Could you also please share the rules and explain what line is causing the issue from your angular app?

Answer (score -1):

To use **ignoreUndefinedProperties** setting, please follow the next steps:

1. Import the firebase-admin sdk (in Typescript):

```
import * as firestore from "firebase-admin";
```

2. Set the setting as following :

```
const db = firestore.firestore();
db.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true })
```

Comment: This is not applicable. I am using firebase hosting so I am importing all the libraries in the index.html and the init.js script from firebase hosting is handling the initializations.

Comment: I know that you are using Firebase Hosting, but I was not able to see this setting in [firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#firebase-json_example). As per [Firebase Javascript SDK Release](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore_21), this setting is for Cloud Firestore, so you in your application as such, should call the firestore client and set the ignoreUndefinedProperties setting.

Comment: @AlexEgli she's right. You need to set up that option in the **code**. It doesn't matter you're using hosting because your angular app will be packaged. Check this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#using-module-bundlers) of the documentation that explains how dependencies are added when using a module bundler such as webpack.

Comment: Yes, it's been confirmed that firebase hosting cannot support handling initialization if you want to setup configuration properties. I'd prefer to let hosting manage the initialization since that handles environment specific config as well, so I just modified my code to do undefined checks on any fields in any doc that is saved to firestore.